# Failed to load plugin 'jsx-a11y' declared in '.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-next/core-web-vitals

Tags: node.js, next.js

Encountered an error during yarn build.

Node version: 18.17.0
Next JS version: 14.0.3
eslint-config-next version: 14.0.3

Already removed node_modules and installing again.
Tried also on node version 20.8.0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Already fixed the problem by deleting node_modules and yarn.lock first before yarn install again